# Retrieving locale out of timezone_identifier -php

Tags: php, timezone, locale

Is there an easy way to retrieve the locale from the `timezone_identifier`?

For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
```

The Locale in that case should `de_DE`.

Comment: maybe better to use browser settings instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297542/simplest-way-to-detect-client-locale-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `deceze` said there is no possiblity of this. But you can get location information from timezone. as [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getlocation.php) says

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Prague"); 
print_r($tz->getLocation());
print_r(timezone_location_get($tz));
```

will output

```
Array
(
 [country_code] => CZ
 [latitude] => 50.08333
 [longitude] => 14.43333
 [comments] => 
)
Array
(
 [country_code] => CZ
 [latitude] => 50.08333
 [longitude] => 14.43333
 [comments] => 
)
```

Comment: this is a good hint - as I have a language-code I can construct the locale out of languagecode and locationinformation, thx

Comment: @casa I was also hoping this.. that from location it can be done. :-)

Comment: @casa How is the location any more helpful in this? Belgium... three languages...?

Answer (score 1):

No, because there's no such 1:1 correlation. Take Belgium for example, where they officially speak three languages in the same timezone.