# possibility of pure php reverse proxy?

Tags: php, proxy, reverse

Let me explain it more here --
I am using BOX1, I want to visit BOX2, but I want to use a domain to visit it(example.com), so my domain is pointing to box1, now how do I get example.com to fetch content from box2 without actually redirecting to IP address of box2?

Comment: a little bit more info as a example. ENTRY SERVER -> get requested url, get location of visitor -> determine best location to goto -> show page

Comment: Possible, but I wouldn't call it advisable.

Comment: any ideas how? I though about cURL but then I didn't think that would work.

Comment: I don't see how that would be any faster. You'd have to detect the location on server A, then if TRUE redirect them to server B. The detection and redirect would take more time than just loading the page on server A.

Comment: Well, even still I want to give it a try just for fun. Any ideas how?

Comment: Start by reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297542/simplest-way-to-detect-client-locale-in-php

Comment: I already know how, already have all those scripts set up in place.

Comment: Then, what are you asking???

Comment: How to use PHP to act as a reverse proxy. EX: I run a get user location on load, then using a reverse proxy like script, find the best server to go to and use it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20665/discussion-between-user1770015-and-relentless)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out thanks to this post: http://techzinger.blogspot.ca/2007/07/writing-reverse-proxy-in-php5.html

Answer (score 0):

Our definition of 'reverse proxy' seems to differ. I tend to towards equating it with load balancing and caching, while you simply want something to issue 301/302 redirects based on a GeoIP lookup.

```
<?php
$servers = array(
    'CA' => array('1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2'),
    'US' => array('3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4')
);

$cc = geoip_country_code_by_name( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );

if( in_array($cc, $servers) ) {
    $server = $servers[$cc][rand(0,count($servers[$cc]))];
} else {
    $server = '5.5.5.5';
}

header('Location: ' . $server);
exit();
```

Comment: I want to mask the server ip, not redirect it. EX: example.com loads to lets say a US server, then example.com/page2.php still loads to same server, but does not redirect to the ip address to load it

Comment: @user1770015 then there is absolutely *zero point* in having servers in other countries. *At best* you will have the same network performance as between the user and the 'proxy', *plus* whatever network delay is between the 'proxy' machine and the server.

Comment: there may be zero point to you, but there is a point to me. now do you know how or not?

Comment: Nope. No idea. I am not a magician, so I cannot perform the particular form of sorcery you require.

Comment: would a curl call be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a very simple reverse proxy in PHP. You basically just take the request parameters and pass them on using curl or file_get_contents. For example:

```
<?php
  $external_url = 'http://www.anotherserver.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . $_REQUEST['QUERY_STRING'];
  print file_get_contents($external_url);
?>
```

Check out [this article](http://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/a-quick-and-dirty-reverse-proxy-with-php/) for more details.

Comment: this may be simple but it doesn't include any kind of headers, cookies, etc. and will very quickly be deemed to be spam.