# In PHP, how do I access the filepath of the current textdomain?

Tags: php, locale, gettext

The function bindtextdomain() will set the path for a given domain, such as en-us. Is there a get-type function that retrieves this path, a "findtextdomain" if you will? If not, how do I determine this path?

Comment: [`locale_get_default()`](http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdefault.php) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22334417/3000179)?

Comment: Looks like either of those is good for retrieving the locale, but not the filepath I'm interested in, e.g. "project/locale/en_us.po" or .mo.